# Android rk322x_box TV box on Andorid 6 tries to occasionally update and fails

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, custom-roms, ota-update

I have an Android TV Box (MXQ-4K) Android/rk322x_box/. This device is on Android 6 and I bought it online; it came pre-rooted. It worked fine and then I stopped using it.

Now after few years, I have started using it again. It worked fine for few days, but now after few months, during YouTube video (which I use it mostly for) it just randomly tries to update without any cancel button, turns off with the DRIOD icon tries to update then the recovery screen appears telling, update aborted, turn off the device.

How can I fix this? Or at least simply disable the auto system update?

[image: v=snap]

Comment: A pre-rooted device from pre 2016? Most likely the manufacturer doesn't exist anymore and thus connecting to the update server fails. You can try to sniff the traffic using an app like PCapDroid and check which servers it tries to contact and then redirect those servers to localhost using entries in the `hosts` file so the update check will fail fast.

Comment: Just remembered that on some devices you can disable system updates in Android developer options, but I am not sure if this also applies on Android TV. Anyway the system updater is a stand-alone app in your system. So with root you may be able to disable or remove it. Bug be aware that there is a chance that disabling or removing ( file renaming) the app may break system boot. Therefore only do it if you have a "back door" like a recovery ROM that you can do to revert your actions in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime my stream smart started acting a fool a factory reset solved all the problems and just rely on kodis add-ons to auto update mine still works like a charm other than a lil slow 2g ram

Comment: But make sure u use reset button on outside of unit. DO NOT use factory reset in system setting as this my be an unrecoverable delete